# ReuseScope.Request not working in mono with self host

Tags: servicestack

I am registering a service with `ReuseScope.Request` and in some cases (read below) I get the exception:

`Error trying to resolve Service 'Ceco.ServiceStack.TestService.TestService' or one of its autowired dependencies (see inner exception for details).`

Basically this registration:

```
container.RegisterAutoWiredAs<FakeAgent, IAgent>().ReusedWithin(ReuseScope.Request);
```

which is required for the service:

```
public class TestService : Service {
        private readonly IAgent _agent;

        public TestService(IAgent agent) {
            _agent = agent;
        }

        public object Get(TestRequest request) {
            return _agent.Process(request);
        }
}
```

is working as expected on Windows via MS.NET with both web application and self host.

On Ubuntu 14.04 via Mono 3.2.8 web application is fine. A console application with a self host (checked all three: `AppSelfHostBase`, `AppHostHttpListenerPoolBase` and `AppHostHttpListenerSmartPoolBase`)  is throwing the aforementioned exception. If I change the `ReuseScope` to `None` it stops complaining but it is not what I want, obviously...

I am using ServiceStack 4.0.20. The above code was working as expected with 3.9.71. The code which can be used to reproduce this is in [a github repo](https://github.com/cvetomirtodorov/Ceco.ServiceStack).

Question: Is this a bug and if yes - is there a workaround or I should just stick to 3.9.71?

UPDATE1:

It seems I cannot force ServiceStack to show me the inner exception. When I add in `Configure`:

```
Config.DebugMode = true;
Config.ReturnsInnerException = true;
```

it just returns the following stack trace (which I think is **not** for the inner exception but just the general failure for not being able to resolve an instance of class implementing `IAgent` service):

Stack Traceat Funq.Container.ResolveImpl (string,bool) <0x0010b> at Funq.Container.ResolveNamed (string) <0x00033> at Funq.Container.Resolve () <0x00027> at (wrapper dynamic-method) object.lambda_method (System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Closure,Funq.Container) <0x00024> at ServiceStack.Host.ContainerResolveCache.CreateInstance (System.Type,bool) <0x00123> at ServiceStack.Host.ContainerResolveCache.CreateInstance (System.Type) <0x0001f> at ServiceStack.Host.ServiceController/<>c__DisplayClass11.b__f (ServiceStack.Web.IRequest,object) <0x000a1> at ServiceStack.Host.ServiceController.Execute (object,ServiceStack.Web.IRequest) <0x000af> at ServiceStack.HostContext.ExecuteService (object,ServiceStack.Web.IRequest) <0x0005f> at ServiceStack.Host.Handlers.ServiceStackHandlerBase.ExecuteService (object,ServiceStack.Web.IRequest) <0x0001b> at ServiceStack.Host.RestHandler.GetResponse (ServiceStack.Web.IRequest,object) <0x00077> at ServiceStack.Host.RestHandler.ProcessRequestAsync (ServiceStack.Web.IRequest,ServiceStack.Web.IResponse,string) <0x005e8>

Comment: I cannot reproduce this error in Mono 3.4.0 (no/c3fc3ba Thu May 1 22:52:17 EDT 2014) on Mac OS X. Runs as expected. What are the details of the inner exception?

Comment: @Scott, I updated my post. Also, I may have not written the post in the best way possible, you checked the self host example, not the web app, right?

Comment: Yeah I ran both the self hosted console app and web app. Both no issues. I also created [my own self hosted test](https://gist.github.com/scottmcarthur/ce07158eb803b8b8fb66) based on on your code, and couldn't recreate the issue either.

Comment: Well, I get the same error using your test. On a side note - any clues why ServiceStack is not showing me the inner exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option to get RequestContext to use ThreadStatic has [been added in ServiceStack v4.0.21](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/release-notes.md#request-scopes-can-be-configured-to-use-threadstatic), e.g:

```
RequestContext.UseThreadStatic = true;
```